# How to customize a filter's name displayed in admin site in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

For example, if I use filter on several foreign key like this:

```
list_filter = ['status', 'species__name', 'factor__name', 'factor__type', ]
```

There will be two filter whose name is displayed as "Name" on the admin site.

[image]

Does anyone have ideas about how to solve this? (by give them different names.)

I think `django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter` may be a solution, but considering that I have 10+ fields like `xxx__name`. It might be a little clumsy..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my debugging i found that `/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/filter.html` is the template which is responsible to render filter related content .
in this template you can found

```
{% blocktrans with filter_title=title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}
```

Here each and every filter's title is coming from `filter_title` 
so to get the value of filter_title you can go to
`/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py` 
Here in `FieldListFilter` class you can see it is directly putting verbose_name into filter.title.
Here you have

```
list_filter = ['status', 'species__name', 'factor__name', 'factor__type', ]
```

you can solve your problem by simply providing verbose name to fields which belong to other table and connected into your model as Foreignkey .

```
#Home  here home is first model
name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Home status", --)
```

```
# Out  here Out is second model 
name = models.CharField(verbose_name="out status", ---)
```

```
#Main this is main model
home = models.ForeignKey(Home)
out = models.ForeignKey(Out)
```

so now if you will use filter it will display filter title as  `Home status and out status`